# Strange warning while installing Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I just tried to install ruby 1.9.3 and it worked but I got a strange error message while it was installing and I'm pretty new to this stuff so I'm not sure if it matters or not. The error is

```
Warning: found user selected compiler '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
```

Can anyone tell me if this will be a problem for me or not?

Thanks

Comment: How are you installing Ruby 1.9.3? Via RVM? Please, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue on GitHub. Try to follow the instructions there: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2331

The solution from the author seems to be:

```
unset CC
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```